# How to open a file using installed apps?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open a given file using installed apps in Android. How can I do that?

I am using the following code from Google but it always returns `"No app to open this file"`. But if I open that file in other file managers, I see different options to open that file. Code:

```
public void open(View v) {
        String name = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        File f = new File(path + name);
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            showFiles(f);
        } else if (f.isFile()) {
            Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            openFileIntent.setData(Uri.fromFile(f));
            if (openFileIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(openFileIntent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No app to open this file.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Selected item is not a file.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a [MIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) type so Android knows which app is capable of opening / viewing the file. This should work for you:

```
public void open(View v) {
    String name = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
    File f = new File(path + name);
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        showFiles(f);
    } else if (f.isFile()) {
        Intent openFileIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        openFileIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(f), getMimeTypeFromFile(f));
        if (openFileIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(openFileIntent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No app to open this file.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Selected item is not a file.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

private String getMimeTypeFromFile(File f){
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
    String fileExtension
            = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(fileUri.toString());
    String fileType 
            = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
    if (fileType == null) 
        fileType = "*/*";
    return fileType;
}
```

Comment: It works. awesome. thanks. I tried many code samples in stackoverflow and internet. It's the only one that I could get working.